# How to create reactive search input field in Vue.js?

Tags: forms, vue.js, vuejs3, html-input, vue-reactivity

I want to build a `seach input field` that sorts an object array **while typing**, using `vue 3` with `script setup`.

`input field`:

```html
<input type="search" placeholder="Search" v-model="state.search">
```

`script setup`:

```js
const state = reactive({
    search: ''
})

const array = [
    {id: 1, title: 'Valhalla', content: '123'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Wurstopia', content: '456'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Brandon', content: '789'}
]

const search  = computed(() => {
    // sort array reactively according to search (use title as sorting criteria)
    const result = sort(array['title'], state.search)
})
```

Is using `computed` the right approach for this? How do I reactively sort the array for `search input` ~ `title`?

If making this `reactive` is a problem, I am also happy with an approach of just submitting the `input` and sorting the `array` afterwards.

**Edit:**

I've tried the approach of @AdriHM but it produces exactly the same unsorted array:

```js
const state = reactive({
    search: '',
    array: [
        {id: 1, title: 'Valhalla', content: '123'},
        {id: 2, title: 'Wurstopia', content: '456'},
        {id: 3, title: 'Brandon', content: '789'}
    ]
})

function mySort(searchKey){
    let matchedKeys = [], notMatchedKeys = [];

    for(let i = 0; i < state.array.length; i++) {
        if (state.array[i]['title'].match(searchKey) ) {
            matchedKeys.push(state.array[i])
        } else{
            notMatchedKeys.push(state.array[i])
        }
    }
}

console.log(mySort(state.search))
```

Output:

```
(3) [Proxy, Proxy, Proxy]
    0: Proxy {id: 1, title: 'Valhalla', content: '123'}
    1: Proxy {id: 2, title: 'Wurstopia', content: '456'}
    2: Proxy {id: 3, title: 'Brandon', content: '789'}
    length: 3
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

Comment: what do you want to do is sort or filter ? Because I think it's more a filter no ?

Comment: @Artur This comment is confusing: `sort array reactively according to search (use title as sorting criteria)`. How would the search affect the sorting? The sorting key is always `title` (the results are always sorted by that key). I would assume the search input is only used for *filtering* (display the results that include the search term).

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is a sort you can do it like this:

```
<template>
  <input type="search" placeholder="Search" v-model="state.search">
  {{ state.array }}
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import {reactive, watch} from "vue";

const state = reactive({
  search: '',
  array: [
    {id: 1, title: 'Valhalla', content: '123'},
    {id: 2, title: 'Wurstopia', content: '456'},
    {id: 3, title: 'Brandon', content: '789'}
  ]
})

function mySort(searchKey: string){
  let matchedKeys = [], notMatchedKeys = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < state.array.length; i++) {
    if (state.array[i]['title'].match(searchKey) ) {
      matchedKeys.push(state.array[i])
    } else{
      notMatchedKeys.push(state.array[i])
    }
  }
  return matchedKeys.concat(notMatchedKeys);
}


watch(() => state.search, () => {
  // sort of filter
  state.array = mySort(state.search)
})
</script>
```

It will only put at first position the element that match the query but you have the logic to make the array changing with `watch`.

Comment: I've tried your approach. Please see the `edit` section

Comment: I think you forget the watch no ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the objective is to filter an array by a search term, and display the results sorted by title.

The sorting itself does not need to be reactive because the array is always sorted by `title`. The array can be sorted once, and then the sorted array can be filtered reactively in the computed prop.

1. Use [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort `array[]` by the `title` field.
2. In the computed prop, use [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to include only items whose `title` or `content` field contains `state.search`. `filter()` does not change the order of the results, so no additional sorting is needed.

```html
<script setup>
import { reactive, computed } from 'vue'

const state = reactive({
  search: '',
})

const array = [
  { id: 1, title: 'Valhalla', content: '123' },
  { id: 2, title: 'Wurstopia', content: '456' },
  { id: 3, title: 'Brandon', content: '789' },
]

1️⃣
array.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title))

const results = computed(() => {
  2️⃣
  return array.filter(item => item.title.includes(state.search) || item.content.includes(state.search))
})
</script>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-sort-and-filter?file=src/components/MySearchInput.vue)